# Angullar FullCalendar custom header button with navigation

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm working in Angular project and I use `fullcalendar` with two views, week and Month, so far it works fine.

Now I'm trying to change the text of the navigation button.
According to the documentation, I created my custom buttons like this:

```
customButtons:{
  customForwardButton: {
    text: 'Next',
    click: function() { }
  },
  customBAckwordButton: {
    text: 'Prev',
    click: function() {  }
  }
},
headerToolbar: {
  left: 'customBAckwordButton,customForwardButton today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek'
}
```

I got the new buttons but when I click on it nothing happens, and  I can't navigate to the month and week view.

How I can keep the default navigation behavior with my new custom buttons?

Comment: The buttons don't do anything because the callbacks are empty. You need to make them call the "next" and "prev" methods in the calendar API

Comment: @ADyson thank for the response i will try to use the calendar API

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I was trying to bind those buttons to an action, this is how I did it (notice the syntax on the click functions):

```
customButtons:{
  customForwardButton: {
    text: 'Next',
    click: this.GoNext.bind(this)
  },
  customBAckwordButton: {
    text: 'Prev',
    click: this.GoPrev.bind(this) 
  }
}
```

where my GoNext and GoPrev are just functions that encapsulate that logic:

```
public GoPrev(){
  var calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
  calendarApi.prev();
  
  ...
}
```